# Plex Server trying to fill my log with UPNP problems

Tags: server, plex

```
Jan 14, 2019 19:37:44.921 [0x7fc5bbbff700] ERROR - SSDP: Error parsing device schema for http://10.20.1.10:8080/upnp
```

This is what Plex Media Server puts in the log. I have an Unifi-network.
PMS is on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1.

Any suggestions what to do?
The IP-number is my Unifi Controller, UPNP is on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check reply #25 in this [thread](https://forums.plex.tv/t/ssdp-error-parsing-device-schema-for-http-x-x-x-x-9080/302731/21).

Excerpt:

I found a simple solution in unfi forum since after using your file I found many entries in console of strange activity

It is a bug in that software. The Unify controller reports that ‘/upnp’ url as a response to SSDP discovery requests, but when it is retrieved it really does return an Apache Tomcat 404 error page.

since this looks like a problem of the Unifi Controller software that does not respond properly to the HTTP queries.

To disable it: go to the Unifi Controller webpage, in the bottom left there is a pair of gears (settings), then pick ‘Controller’, which has a ‘Controller Settings’ section where you find a ‘Network Discovery’ checkbox. Unchecking that checkbox will make the controller not respond to SSDP discovery requests.